# Show that the half-open intervals $J(\Bbb R^n)$ in $\Bbb R^n$ are $\cap$-stable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

My initial problem is that I actually do not understand why the statement is true.

Here is my counter example. Take $I,I´\in J (\Bbb R^n)$ such that $I \cap I´= \emptyset$. Clearly $\emptyset \not \in J(\Bbb R^n)$, since $\emptyset$ is not a half-open interval.

Here is the definition of $\cap$-stable:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Stable_under_Intersection

Comment: You are right. But half open intervals together with the empty set is closed under finite intersections.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But who says that the empty set is included ? The reason I'm asking this question is because I'm working on this problem: 

**Show that the half-open intervals $J(\Bbb R^n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are stable under finite intersections.**

Comment: In the real line $[a,b)$ is the empty set when $a=b$. So when the statement is made they are considering empty set also as a half open interval.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: There is a hint in the problem. I solved the problem without the hint: $$\left.X_{i=1}^{n}\left[a_{i}, b_{i}\right) \cap X_{i=1}^{n}\left[a_{i}^{\prime}, b_{i}^{\prime}\right)=X_{i=1}^{n}\left[a_{i} \vee a_{i}^{\prime}, b_{i} \wedge b_{i}^{\prime}\right) .\right]$$

I do not understand the right side of the equation.

Comment: $[a,b) \cap [c,d) =[e,f)$ where $e= a \vee c$ is the  maximum of  $a$ and $c$ and $f=b\wedge d$ is the minimum of $b$ and $d$.

Comment: Thanks. Then it is the same as what I have done. (I read the notation wrong)